# My Android App crashes on the load of JSON data in the recyclerview using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm pretty new at developing. I'm busy creating an app that reads JSON data into an recycler view on button click. Here is my Activity code:

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

var userId: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var firstName: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var lastName: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var mail: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)

private var requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
    title = "Pending Approvals"

    val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    jsonRequestParse()

    val buttonSubmit: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit)
    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

private fun jsonRequestParse() {
    val url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1"

    val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            null, { response -> try {
            val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data")
            for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                val user = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                userId.add(user.getString("id"))
                firstName.add(user.getString("first_name"))
                lastName.add(user.getString("last_name"))
                mail.add(user.getString("email"))

                val customAdapter = CustomAdapter(this@MainActivity2, userId,
                        firstName, lastName, mail)
                recyclerView.adapter = customAdapter

            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }, { error -> error.printStackTrace() })
    requestQueue?.add(request)
}
}
```

Here is my Adapter Code:

```
class CustomAdapter(
    private var context: Context,
    private var id: ArrayList<String>,
    private var first_name: ArrayList<String>,
    private var last_name: ArrayList<String>,
    private var email: ArrayList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.userId.text = id[position]
    holder.firstName.text = first_name[position]
    holder.lastName.text = last_name[position]
    holder.mail.text = email[position]

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return id.size
}

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var userId: TextView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tvID) as TextView
    var firstName: TextView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tvFirstName) as TextView
    var lastName: TextView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tvLastName) as TextView
    var mail: TextView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tvEmail) as TextView
}
```

I'm pretty sure the error lies somewhere in my loading of the recycler view.
Thanks in advance

Edit:

Errors from logcat

```
2021-01-19 09:37:25.908 8620-8620/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 8620
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:173)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:744)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:692)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:214)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity2.<init>(MainActivity2.kt:21)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2021-01-19 09:37:25.966 8620-8620/com.example.myapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8620 SIG: 9
```

Comment: show exception stacktrace from logcat

Comment: You should post your error as well so people can know what error you are getting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @Fourie, dont invoke `findViewById` even before the views are inflated, move the initialization of global variable ` recyclerView` after `setContentView()` or use `lateinit` modifier

Comment: Is MainActivity2 declared in the Manifest?

Comment: @IvanWooll OP is doing a findViewById outside onCreate, so that won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error is here:

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

  ...

  var recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView) 
  ...
```

you can't do a `findViewById` outside the scope of your onCreate like you're doing, onCreate has to be called first:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
var recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)  //probably no need to use these as var, it could probably be val
```

---

alternatively:

```
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView //here, we are saying that we will initialize this later

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
```